# IIS 7 does not fire Application Error in Global.asax while migrating a HTML application to ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: iis-7, global-asax, application-error

I am migrating a HTML site to ASP.Net 4.0 web application. If someone types an existing HTML page URL, I want to redirect them to a corresponding ASP page.

I have already tried below suggestions, nothing worked out.

1. included Custom Errors tag which redirects to some asp page in web.config - not worked

   ```
   enter code here
   <customErrors mode="On">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error.aspx" />
   </customErrors>
   enter code here
   ```
2. included below code under Application_Error method in the Global.asax page.  - It does not fire

   ```
   enter code here

   void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
           string fullOrginalpath = Request.Url.ToString();
           string strPathExtn = 
               Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension.ToString();
           if (fullOrginalpath.Contains(".html"))
           {
               Server.ClearError();
               Response.Clear();
               fullOrginalpath = fullOrginalpath.Replace(".html", ".aspx");
               Response.Redirect(fullOrginalpath);
           }           
       }
   enter code here
   ```
3. Tried having httpErrors tag in web.cofig - it throws 500 internal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to look at the IIS URL Rewrite module:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: Thanks for you valuable suggestions which worked fine.